# Android to ffmpeg preview frame is grayscale

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

Hi im using `android` and `ffmpeg` together to stream to a Wowza Server. In the `android` part, I have only this:

```
public synchronized void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
/* get video data */
naStream(data); // native method
}
```

And on native side using `ffmpeg` (frame_video is the byte array from `android`):

```
    av_init_packet(&pkt);
    avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)picture,frame_video,PIX_FMT_YUV420P,640,480);

        if(ret == 0)
            LOGI(7,"avpicture_fill -> error %d", ret);

        /* encode the image */
        pkt.data = NULL;
        pkt.size = 0;

        ret = avcodec_encode_video2(video_c, &pkt, picture, &got_packet);

        if(ret != 0)
            LOGI(7,"avcodec_encode_video2 -> error %d", ret);

        /* if zero size, it means the image was buffered */
        if (got_packet) {
            if (pkt.pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE) {
                pkt.pts = av_rescale_q(picture->pts, video_c->time_base, AV_TIME_BASE_Q);
            }
            if (pkt.dts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE) {
                pkt.dts = av_rescale_q(pkt.dts, video_c->time_base, AV_TIME_BASE_Q);
            }

            pkt.duration = av_rescale_q(video_st->duration, video_c->time_base, video_st->time_base);

            if (video_c->coded_frame->key_frame)
                pkt.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;

            /* write the compressed frame in the media file */
            ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(oc, &pkt);
```

The issue in here is that the stream arrives in a grayscale...
**I tried to convert from NV21 to YUV420P using:**

```
img_convert_ctx = sws_getContext(video_c->width, video_c->height,PIX_FMT_NV21, video_c->width, video_c->height,PIX_FMT_YUV420P,SWS_FAST_BILINEAR | SWS_PRINT_INFO, NULL, NULL, NULL);

sws_scale(img_convert_ctx, (const uint8_t * const*)picture->data, picture->linesize, 0,video_c->height, tmp_picture->data, tmp_picture->linesize);

sws_freeContext(img_convert_ctx);
```

But then i cannot write_interleaved packets...

Im doing the "**picture**" and "**tmp_picture**" allocations like this:

```
picture = avcodec_alloc_frame();
tmp_picture = avcodec_alloc_frame();

numBytes=avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_YUV420P, video_c->width, video_c->height);
buffer=(uint8_t *)av_malloc(numBytes*sizeof(uint8_t));

avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)tmp_picture, buffer, PIX_FMT_YUV420P,video_c->width, video_c->height);
```

---

After i delete the following lines:

```
if (pkt.pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE) {
                pkt.pts = av_rescale_q(picture->pts, video_c->time_base, AV_TIME_BASE_Q);
            }
            if (pkt.dts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE) {
                pkt.dts = av_rescale_q(pkt.dts, video_c->time_base, AV_TIME_BASE_Q);
            }
```

And added:

```
if (video_c->coded_frame->pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE)
  pkt.pts = av_rescale_q(video_c->coded_frame->pts,video_c->time_base, video_st->time_base);
```

It started writing the interleaved packets but in wowza i cannot see any thing...
Can anyone help me with this?